# Overlapping content when resizing columns in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to code a resizable table using **jQuery** & **jQuery UI**'s `resizable()` to achieve that.

I'm facing an issue using Firefox where the content of a cell is overlaying on another cell when the text is greater then the column width.

I created a fiddle with my table: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g51kk772/2/)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this below link ..maybe it works for you..

jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/

By this you can adjust column width easily..

```
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  width:auto;
  border: 2px dashed #f0f;
```

Use Width as auto   for resize any columns of table

If not worked .Check this new link..
hope it will help you

ihofmann.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/resizable-table-columns-with-jquery-ui/

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I'm trying to not use plugins other of jQuery UI.